# Do `id` attributes need to be unique across iframes?

Tags: html, iframe

For instance, is this valid?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Some Iframes</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <iframe id="frame1" src="/html/test-frame.html"></iframe>
    <iframe id="frame2" src="/html/test-frame.html"></iframe>
  </body>

</html>
```

Where the file `test-frame.html` has the contents:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Test Iframe</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="subscribe">Subscribe</button>
  </body>

 </html>
```

I would like to be able to use the same html and the same scripts for a set of iframes.

Comment: Do you actually have content in the `iframe` elements? It would be ignored by all frames-capable browsers, which means all browsers except perhaps when especially configured to pretend they don’t do frames. Did you mean that the `iframe` elements have `src` attributes referring to documents that contain identical elements?

Comment: Yes. I updated the example to make it less contrived.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's acceptable and valid. As each page is self-contained and therefore has its own individual namespace and DOM, there's no harm in using the same ID across iframes as long as it only occurs once within each iframe document.

Comment: My mistake. It turns out that the buttons are simply treated as fallback content for user agents that don't support iframes.

Comment: The example was contrived. I'll edit it to actually pull the iframes from sources, which is how I'm implementing.

Answer (score 3):

Each page ***inside*** of an iframe is totally self-contained and unique.

You can have a page and 4 iframes, and each one can have an element called `"#the-element"`.
Of course, the code that you have there is invalid, but if each loaded its own separate HTML, that would be perfectly acceptable.